# How do I prevent this upload script from executing if it does not have the appropriate input

Tags: php

I have an upload form which is going to upload only six images with JPG and PNG formats.

The problem is: Whenever I'm selecting two GIF images and four JPG images, it's uploading the JPG and rejecting the GIF. How can I do a validation for this that if there is only one GIF image the error message occurs and other five JPGs should not be uploaded?

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
    if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']))
    {
        echo 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field'; 
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) 
        {
            // Allowed file types
            $whitelist = array("jpg","png");
            $temp = explode('.', $file);
            // Match uploaded file extension
            if (in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 
            {
                // Count total uploads
                if (count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'])==6) 
                {
                    // Code for uploading here
                    echo 'Image &nbsp;  <b>' .$file.'</b>  &nbsp; uploaded successfully<br>';
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Count error 
                    echo 'You\'r Only Allowed Six Images';
                    exit();
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                // File extension error
                echo 'Image  &nbsp;  <b>'.$file.'</b>  &nbsp;  Must be JPG OR PNG<br>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to allow only a single gif?

Comment: No i am allowing only JPG AND PNG if some one upload 2 image from GIF and 4 from JPG so the process must fail but my current code will upload the 4 JPG and reject the 2 GIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$errors = array();

if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'][0])) {
    $errors[] = 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field'; 
}
else {

    if (count($_FILES) > 6)
        $errors[] = "Your Only Allowed Six Images";

    $whitelist = array("jpg","png");

    foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) {
        if ($file) { 

            $temp = explode('.', $file);

            if (!in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) {
                $errors[] = "All images must be JPG and PNG";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        foreach ($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) {

            if ($file) {
                // Code for uploading here
                // ...
                echo 'Image &nbsp;  <b>' .$file.'</b>  &nbsp; uploaded successfully<br>';
            }

        }
    }
}

if (!empty($errors))
    foreach ($errors as $e)
        echo $e."<br/>";
```

Comment: billions thanks its working if there was any issue i will post.

Comment: You welcome. I just made one final change to print the name of each uploaded file